# Apache URL Rewrite Rule

Tags: rewrite

I'm trying to configure the rewrite rules for my application, my requirement are

1. `/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/ -> ./index.php?aaa=$1&bbb=$2&ccc=$3&ddd=$4`
2. `/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd -> ./index.php?aaa=$1&bbb=$2&ccc=$3&ddd=$4`
3. `/aaa/bbb/ccc/ -> ./index.php?aaa=$1&bbb=$2&ccc=$3&ddd=`
4. `/aaa/bbb/ccc -> ./index.php?aaa=$1&bbb=$2&ccc=$3&ddd=`

With the rule only the URL no. 1 & 2 are working, but no. 3 & 4 are not working, may someone can help to correct the rule, thanks in advance!

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(/?)(.*?)$ ./index.php?aaa=$1&bbb=$2&ccc=$3&ddd=$4 [L]
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(/)?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?(/)?(.*)?$  ./index.php?aaa=$1&bbb=$2&ccc=$4&ddd=$6 [L]